# Improving branch coverage with Istanbul

Tags: javascript, angularjs, code-coverage, istanbul

The following code snippet has only 50% branch coverage (see below for coverage report)
I'm not sure how to improve this since there are no `if` statements.

I'm thinking Istanbul must do some sort of measuring that i don't fully understand, any pointers are appreciated.

```
angular
.module("konakFront", [
    "ngRoute"
])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    "use strict";
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "views/main.html",
            controller: "MainCtrl"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
});
```

[image: Istanbul Coverage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was related due to the accidental double instrumentation of the file.
More info can be found here:

https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/123